# Can't order when the field name is "date" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a `Game` model with fields `start_time` and `date` (amongst others). `@tournament.games.order('start_time asc')` works, but `@tournament.games.order('date asc')` doesn't work. `t.games.order("date asc")` and `t.games.order("date desc")` produce the same order. Why is that?

Here's my schema for games:

```
create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "tournament_id", null: false
  t.string "team_one_type", null: false
  t.bigint "team_one_id", null: false
  t.string "team_two_type", null: false
  t.bigint "team_two_id", null: false
  t.bigint "field_id", null: false
  t.date "date"
  t.datetime "start_time"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.index ["field_id"], name: "index_games_on_field_id"
  t.index ["team_one_type", "team_one_id"], name: "index_games_on_team_one_type_and_team_one_id"
  t.index ["team_two_type", "team_two_id"], name: "index_games_on_team_two_type_and_team_two_id"
  t.index ["tournament_id"], name: "index_games_on_tournament_id"
end
```

Comment: can you try `@tournament.games.order('date asc').to_sql`, get the sql and try if the sql works directly

Comment: just saw the `schema`, could this be just because you search only by the date (and the records with the same date will not change), however, if you sort by `DateTime` every record will sort (including the records in the same date)

Comment: @muistooshort Sorry about that. I meant that things weren't coming out in the expected order. `t.games.order("date asc")` and `t.games.order("date desc")` give the same order.

Comment: @sameera207 That's it, thanks! The issue is that the records had the same date. When records don't have the same date I'm able to order by date. Would you like write up an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be just because you search only by the date (and the records with the same date will not change), however, if you sort by DateTime every record will sort (including the records in the same date).